# When $\operatorname{im}(A) = \ker(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following true/ false qustion:

> There exists a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ such that $\operatorname{im}(A) = \ker(A)$.

I know that this is true, but I am not sure how to show it.

If $A$ has rank $1$ then either the image is $[a,0]$ and the kernel is $t[0,1]$, or the image is $[0,a]$ and the kernel is $t[1,0]$, and we can set $t = a$.

So I am not sure how they could be the same?

Comment: If rank is $1$ then you are saying something about the image and kernel.. I suggest you to check than one more time.. It may not be correct..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik From the rank-nullity theorem follows that $rank A=dim (Ker A)=1$

Comment: I have said nothing about rank and dimension... I was commenting on the image and kernel.. @Svetoslav

Comment: I didn't get what you mean, but nevermind :) @PraphullaKoushik

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have $Im(A)=Ker(A)$ in particular,  $A(Av)=0$ i.e., $A^2=0$.

There are some standard $2\times 2$ matrices with $0$ and $1$ such that $A^2=0$..

Take any one of them and compute its image and kernel..

Comment: Does it holds for all nilpotent matrices? $Im(A)=Ker(A)$?

Comment: @gbox : Nipotent matrices are such that $A^k=0$ for some $k$ which may not imply $A^2=0$... So, it may be true for all nilpotent matrices..

Answer (score 9):

Hint: compose a orthogonal projection and a rotation.

Comment: The visualization of this is really nice, +1.

Answer (score 1):

The dimension theorem gives
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{dim}{dim}
\DeclareMathOperator{im}{im}
2 = \dim(\ker(A) + \dim(\im(A)) = \dim(S) + \dim(S) = 2 \dim(S) \Rightarrow \\
\dim(S) = 1
$$
Further 
$$
A x \in \im(A) = \ker(A) \Rightarrow \\
A(Ax) = 0 
$$
This gives
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
=
A^2
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a^2 + bc & b(a+d) \\
c(a+d) & d^2 + bc
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This gives
$$
0 = a^2 + bc = d^2 + bc \iff \\
a^2 = d^2 \Rightarrow \\
a = \pm d
$$
and
$$
0 = b(a+d) = c (a+d)
$$
Case 1: If $a + d \ne 0 \iff a \ne -d$ this means $b = c$.
So we try
$$
0 =
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
b & a
\end{pmatrix}^2
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a^2 + b^2 & 2ab \\
2ab & a^2 + b^2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This choice leaves only $a = b = c = d = 0$.

Case 2: If $a + d = 0 \iff d = -a$ we get
$$
0 = a^2 + bc
$$
For $b \ne 0$ we get
$$
c = -a^2/b 
$$
or for $c \ne 0$:
$$
b = -a^2 / c
$$
So
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
-a^2/b & -a
\end{pmatrix}
\quad (b \ne 0)  
$$
or
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & -a^2/c \\
c & -a
\end{pmatrix}
\quad (c \ne 0)
$$
Checking:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{rr|r}
a & b & 0 \\
-a^2/b & -a & 0
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{rr|r}
a & b & 0 \\
-a^2 & -ab & 0
\end{array}
\right]
\to
\left[
\begin{array}{rr|r}
a & b & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
$$
$$
\ker(A) = \{ \lambda (1, -a/b) \mid \lambda \in F \}
$$
Further
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
-a^2/b & -a
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a x + b y \\
(-a^2/b)x -a y 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a x + b y \\
(-a/b)(a x + b y) 
\end{pmatrix}
\in \im(A)
$$

Comment: why do you conclude that $A x \in \im(A) = \ker(A) \Rightarrow 
A(Ax) = 0 $?

Comment: $y=Ax \in \ker(A)$ means $0 = Ay = A(Ax) = A^2 x$.